# Adding a vector layer at QGIS start

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have added a shapefile in QGIS using Python plugin. I want to add this shapefile when QGIS is loading so I have to add code in the initgui() method.

I have used following code in the initgui() method:

```
self.iface.addVectorLayer("C:/abc.shp","Global","ogr")
```

But when I open QGIS it asks me to save the file but not add/show the shapefile whether I saved  it or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like that QGIS creates a new empty project after the initialization.
But if you want to open Qgis with the same layer/project you can first save your layer into a project and then define that the project opens on launch. You can find it here:

`Options-> General-> Project files-> Open projects on launch`

Answer (score 5):

An alternative option would be to call the addVectorLayer method within python macro openProject function (Project>Project Properties | Macros):

```
def openProject():
    from qgis.utils import iface
    iface.addVectorLayer("c:/Temp/AA/counties.shp", "ccounty", "ogr")
    pass
```

[image]